# PHP and MySQL T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING Error

Tags: php, mysql, token

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Here's the full code.

```
<?php
$country = "UNKNOWN";
if ($_REQUEST['id'] == "register") {
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    if ($_POST['Email'] == $_POST['emailrepeat']) {
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['PasswordAgain']) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    $address = $_POST['Address'];
    $county = $_POST['billingState'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $zip = $_POST['Zip'];
    $code = rand(11212,123243132);
    mysql_connect("extraterrestrial.x10.mx","extrater","*******");
    mysql_select_db("extrater_keys");
    $moi = "VALUES ("$name","1","0","$password","$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']","0","$country","0","$county","$country","$city","$email","$zip","$address","$code")";
    $query = "('INSERT INTO info (name, points, isvalidated, password, ip, banned, cc, paypal, state, country, city, email, fullname, zipcode, address, code)"; }
    mail($email, "Le Prizes Confirmation E-Mail", "Thank you for registering with us! Your confirmation link is as follows. \n http://extraterrestrial.x10.mx/confirm.php?code=" + $code + " Happy Earning!");
header( "Location: thanks.php" );
?>
```

This is my GPT process script, it's going to register the user. It's made by me.

Comment: Perfect script for SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you? How can I fix that too, I can make you an admin on my site if you help make it secure!

Answer (score 2):

```
mail($email, "Le Prizes Confirmation E-Mail", "Thank you for registering with us! Your confirmation link is as follows. \n http://extraterrestrial.x10.mx/confirm.php?code=" . $code . " Happy Earning!");
```

Try this first off, you were adding `$code` instead of concatenating.

Additionally,

```
$moi = "VALUES ('$name','1','0','$password','" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "','0','$country','0','$county','$country','$city','$email','$zip','$address','$code')";
```

is a better line than what you had before, because the other line had " within " unescaped and was therefore terminating the string each time.

Also, let's not forget SQL injection! Sanitize your inputs before inserting them into the database.

Comment: In addition, `$moi` isn't properly defined either. Those variables aren't actually concatenated into his string.

Comment: What's wrong with `$moi`

Comment: I did what you said, used your edits, but the script isn't making a ro for me in my database!

Comment: Try calling `echo(mysql_error());` after the insert, there may be a syntax error in your mysql statement.

Comment: No SQL Error but still no row either.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$moi = "VALUES ("$name","1","0","$password","$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']","0","$country","0","$county","$country","$city","$email","$zip","$address","$code")";
```

contains parse errors. Change it by:

```
$moi = "VALUES ('$name','1','0','$password','{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}','0','$country','0','$county','$country','$city','$email','$zip','$address','$code')";
```

As Cyclone mentions you should also sanitize your data before sending it to your mysql server. Use mysql_real_escape_string

http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

And take into the consideration the possibility to use mysqli instead of mysql too:

http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Sanitization is compulsory because you must escape single quotation marks ' with the escape character secuence \' in these vars: $name, $password, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $country, $county, $city, $email, $zip, $address and $code

Answer (score 0):

You've goofed on the quotes (among other things) when assigning to `$moi`.

Comment: How can I fix that? What quotes do I remove?

Comment: Have you actually tried reading your code?